# click event working in IE 10 but not working in IE 11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, angular7

As mentioned, click event in the given code is working in Chrome,Edge and IE 10 but not in IE 11. 
Code:

```
<div class="text-center" [ngClass]="{'well': showMod === false}">
        <img
          (click)="openWindow()"
          class="bot bot-open"
          src="./assets/images/abc.png"
          style="
            height: 70px;
            left: 0;
            margin: 0 0 5px 0;
            cursor: pointer;
          "/>
        </div>
```

The following classes are present in Polyfills.ts for browser compatibility of IE 11.

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';


/**
 * Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`
 * Only required if AnimationBuilder is used within the application and using IE/Edge or Safari.
 * Standard animation support in Angular DOES NOT require any polyfills (as of Angular 6.0).
 **/
import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.

/**
 * By default, zone.js will patch all possible macroTask and DomEvents
 * user can disable parts of macroTask/DomEvents patch by setting following flags
 */

 // (window as any).__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true; // disable patch requestAnimationFrame
 // (window as any).__Zone_disable_on_property = true; // disable patch onProperty such as onclick
 // (window as any).__zone_symbol__BLACK_LISTED_EVENTS = ['scroll', 'mousemove']; // disable patch specified eventNames

 /*
 * in IE/Edge developer tools, the addEventListener will also be wrapped by zone.js
 * with the following flag, it will bypass `zone.js` patch for IE/Edge
 */
// (window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;

/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.
```

I have searched other posts and they all suggest to make changes in Polyfill.ts that is already done.
When I zoom the page out, the click is working but when i zoom back in, it stops working. The image is located at bottom left corner

Comment: what does `openWindow` do?

Comment: it is a function which toggles a boolean value. originally the boolean value is false.

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem on my side, can you post the related code in the .ts file(especially the openWindow function) to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Besides, you could also use F12 developer tools to check whether there is some error, or set some debugger and use visual studio code to debug your code.

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT HI, New observation.. When I zoom out the page,the click event starts to work and when I zoom back to normal, the click feature stops. The image with click event is present at the bottom right end.

Comment: openWindow() {
    this.showMod= true;   
  }